# Picasso loads image, even when there is not image url at a specific position in recyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I have strange behaviour in my recyclerview which i can not figure out. I am using following code in my OnBindViewHolder()

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductAdapter.OurViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Product currentItem = adapterData.get(i);
    viewHolder.productNamesFragmentItemsBinding.setProductName(currentItem);
    if (currentItem.getPhotoUris() != null) {
        Picasso.get().load(currentItem.getPhotoUris().get(0))
                .into(viewHolder.productNamesFragmentItemsBinding.ivProductImage);
    }
    if (mViewModel.isCartContainsThisProduct(currentItem.getIdProducts())) {
        System.out.println("calling is cart contains");
        viewHolder.productNamesFragmentItemsBinding.btnAddToCart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.productNamesFragmentItemsBinding.btnAdded.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.productNamesFragmentItemsBinding.btnCancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        System.out.println("calling cart not contains");
        viewHolder.productNamesFragmentItemsBinding.btnAddToCart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.productNamesFragmentItemsBinding.btnAdded.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.productNamesFragmentItemsBinding.btnCancel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

I have five items in my adapter , at position 2 there is no url, still it loads the image sometimes but not always.

One more thing i noticed that there is a button "Add to cart", which refresh item at this position when clicked. So if i click this button at any position say at position 5, then again if i click at position 2 (where i have no url), image of position 5 loads at 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not strange behavior at all . This is how `RecyclerView` works its basically reuse the same `ViewHolder` for next items.
The problem with your code you have covers `if (currentItem.getPhotoUris() != null)` case you have missed the `else` part i.e clearing the image or setting a placeholder.

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(currentItem.getPhotoUris())) {
    Picasso.get().load(currentItem.getPhotoUris().get(0))
        .into(viewHolder.productNamesFragmentItemsBinding.ivProductImage);
}else{
    // you can set a placeholder image here
    viewHolder.productNamesFragmentItemsBinding.ivProductImage.setImageResource(0)
}
```